# Angularjs implementing google maps not being rendered

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to include google maps in my side-project and i can't seem to know why this doesn't work after watching countless tutorials. One way I was able to do a work around was to include the src script in right below the init function on the html and then on the controller file write the initMap() function outside the 
angular.module('breazehomeDesktop').controller(). Can someone please help?

this is my html

```
!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Tab Title -->
  <title>Local Scoop</title>
  <!-- Javascript Import-->
  <script src="../scripts/controllers/localscoop.js"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY_GOES HERE"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="breazehomeDesktop" ng-controller="LocalScoopCtrl">
  <!-- MAP -->
  <div id="map" ng-init="initMap()">
    <script>initMap()</script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my controller

```
angular.module('breazehomeDesktop').controller('LocalScoopCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location, $localStorage, $routeParams, $anchorScroll, $http, Properties, Amenities, Bilingual,toasts,Users,Crime, Map, BASE_URL, IMAGE_URL, ModalService, History) {
    $scope.initMap = function (){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
            zoom:8,
            center: {
                latitude:25.7617,
                longitude:-80.191790
            }
        }
      )};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anywhere you've mentioned **`ng-controller`** and use **`ng-init`** to call the method

```
<body ng-app="breazehomeDesktop" ng-controller="LocalScoopCtrl">
 <div id="map" ng-init="initMap()" >
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for that but it still doesn't seem to work on chrome dev tools i get an error of "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError"

Comment: that is something related to google map api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795150/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-initmap-is-not-a-function