# Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function on specific phone

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

An android app use webview, the web use google map to locate my location.

Most phones are worked, but don't know somehow in zenfone 3 552KL, it's not work.

below its my error msg

p.s.permission checked

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(119)] "Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function", source:
```

Using that phone use chrome to open that web with google map is also not work
,but using pc or other phone work...

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795150/uncaught-invalidvalueerror-initmap-is-not-a-function   if any provided solution work in this case

Comment: try `adb logcat` also for debugging in console

Comment: I already read that not worded

Comment: The msg is from android studio run

Comment: is `initMap` is available in final/main `js` ? cross check in the final version in debug mode.